# Realm app compiles on device but not on simulator on Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, cocoapods

I have a `Realm` app that was running fine in `Xcode 11` in both, the device and the Simulator. I recently updated to `Xcode 12` and now the app doesn't compile in any of the Simulators but works fine on physical devices. After researching I noticed that `Realm` suggests adding some build settings in your `Podfile` to exclude the `arm64`, so I went and added it but I'm still getting errors.

Here is what I have done in more detail.

**Original Podfile looked like this**:

```
def shared_pods
    pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.18'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    use_frameworks!
    platform :ios, '10.0'

    shared_pods
    
    target 'MyAppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
    
    target 'MyAppUITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end

target 'MyApp Watch App' do
    use_frameworks!
    platform :watchos, '3.1'
    
    # Pods for MyApp Watch App
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp Watch App Extension' do
    use_frameworks!
    platform :watchos, '3.1'
    shared_pods
end
```

Here is what I did step by step.

1. I compiled my app for the first time in Xcode 12 and I got the following error.

[image]

2. I modified my PodFile to what [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) recommends adding the following code at the end of the Podfile.

   ```
    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
                config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=watchsimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
                config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=appletvsimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
            end
        end
    end
   ```
3. In the terminal I entered `pod install`.
4. Recompiled my project and it got rid of the first error but it now shows the following error.

[image]

Any idea what could be wrong now?

Comment: The linker in Xcode 12 was changed, so Realm itself needs to be updated to be compatible with Xcode 12. If it hasn't yet been updated, I'd suggest opening a GitHub issue for Realm-Swift.

Comment: @DávidPásztor - You're back, the `Realm` community misses you (seriously).  I tried updating my `Realm` from `3.18` to the latest stable version `5.5.0` but it didn't work. Now, but why it works on the device if they changed the linker?

Comment: Sadly I haven't been using Realm for quite a while now, hence my disappearance. I do appreciate the kind words though :) As for the linker issue, somehow only the simulator architecture linking got messed up, I've encountered the [same issue with Onfido](https://github.com/onfido/onfido-ios-sdk/issues/180), which simply needed rebuilding with Xcode 12, so probably Realm needs the same. Though if your using Cocoapods, the whole Realm project should be built using Xcode 12, so maybe this is a different issue. [This might be related though](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6785).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case upgrading `Realm` to the latest version, `10.1.0` and updating `cocoapods` to `1.10.0` solved the issue, I can now compile on the Simulator.